# Store data and display it in another activity using sharedpreferences (Newer Version)

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

*I'm new in learning android

I'm searching for any website that show on how to accept user detail for example name and age, and display it in another activity using sharedpreferences in newer version of code? Do you have any? The another activity will have a Back button pointing to the first activity. All I found was in older version and not matched in my Android Studio so, I've cancelled the program. Anyone?

Comment: Can you share the code you tried and what error message you saw that caused it to "not matched?"

Comment: do you know that there is official [doc](https://developer.android.com) for android, check the SharedPref page [here](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/shared-preferences.html) I am pretty sure it is updated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the first activity, you can save the user name and age like this:

```
private void saveUserInformation(String userName, int age) {
        //In this activity save the name in the shared preference
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("myAppPrefs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        sharedPreferences.edit().putString("user_name", userName).putInt("user_age", age).apply();
    }
```

In the second activity, to get the user information, do this:

```
private void getUserInformation() {
        //In the second activity or any other activity, you can get the userName and age like thi
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("myAppPrefs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        String userName = sharedPreferences.getString("user_name", null);
        int userAge = sharedPreferences.getInt("user_age", 0);
    }
```

From your question and comment in other answers, i guess you need more explanation on how a shared preference works. When you save data in a sharedpreference, it gets saved in a file on the user device. After saving you can access that data from any activity as long as the activity has access. All you just have to do is put it in a shared preference using a unique key and get it where you need it using that same unique key. Hope it helps. If i my answer helps, don't forget to upvote. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. I will try it now.

Comment: Okay, let me know when you are done. Also, if my answer was helpful, don't forget to upvote. Thanks.

Comment: Okey. Don't worry. :)

Comment: it said the private method saveuserInformation is never used. Can you help me out of that error?

Comment: When you want to save a user info, you just call the method passing in the details. Like this: saveUserInformation("Vega Maya", 18) . Android studio is giving you the warning because you are not calling the method.

Answer (score 0):

this is how you create a sharedpref

```
SharedPreferences sp=getSharedPreferences("MYPREFNAME", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

SharedPreferences.Editor editor=sp.edit;
```

this is how you put data in it

```
editor.putString(key,string);
```

this.is how you retrieve that string back

```
sp.getString(key,DefaultString);
```

Answer (score -1):

//in your first activity use

```
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences=getSharedPreferences("your_packagename", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
sharedPreferences.edit().putString("name","name_value").apply();

sharedPreferences.edit().putInt("age",age_value).apply();
```

//and now in your second activity to retrieve data

```
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences=getSharedPreferences("your_packagename", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
String name=sharedPreferences.getString("name","");
int age =sharedPreferences.getInt("age",0);
```

Comment: I can't get it. Is it created in both of activities? I want the first activity store the name, age and the second activity just view them and have a back button pointing to the first activity.

Comment: Is there any code that I have to put in submitbutton method?

Comment: No..just put this code inside your Activity..and it will be work for you